# Permission denied on file owned by user with Perl and Cron

Tags: perl, apache, logging, cron, permission-denied

I searched extensively and couldn't find anything specifically like this.

I have a log file owned and writable by "apache" in a directory also owned and writable by "apache":

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache 0 Apr  9 16:43 /var/log/apache2/load.log
```

I have a Perl program "load.pl" with the following:

```
my $log = "/var/log/apache2/load.log";
my $error = "";

#...doing useful stuff here, where $error might get set

if ($error && $log)
{
    if (open (LOG, '>>$log'))
    {
            print LOG "[".localtime(time)."] ".$error."\n";
            close (LOG);
    }
    else
    {
            my $reason = $!;
            $error .= "Could not open log file as ".getpwuid($>)." (really ".getpwuid($<)."): $reason";

            my $subject = "load.pl could not write to $log";
            $error .= email($mailto, $replyto, $subject, $error);
    }
}
```

Where $mailto, $replyto, and the email() subroutine are defined and work correctly.

I run this program via crontab as follows:

```
*/1 * * * *     apache  flock -x -w 10 /home/web/load.txt -c "perl /home/web/load.pl> /home/web/load.txt 2>&1"
```

Load.txt gets the STDOUT, which is some website load statistics in JSON format to be called from JavaScript, while any caught errors are supposed to be written to load.log.  Everything works fine except the log writing.

I get emailed the following output...

```
Subject: load.pl could not write to /var/log/apache2/load.log
Could not open log file as apache (really apache): Permission denied
```

So clearly Perl is executing this program as "apache" -- both effective and real UID.  But I'm getting permission denied on a file owned by apache in a directory owned by apache.

Comment: Is it working if you execute the script straight with user apache, not through cron?

Comment: Good question!  The cron part above is probably superfluous information because the same thing happens if I run `sudo -u apache load.pl`.

Comment: Running as root does not work either, but instead of permission denied, it says: `Could not open log file as root (really root): Inappropriate ioctl for device`.  This "Inappropriate ioctl for device" is actually not on the open, but on the print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of single quotes will not expand the variable:

```
if (open (LOG, '>>$log'))
```

Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Stupid, stupid me!  I actually figured this out and came to post the solution and found you beat me to it.  This is what I get for being lazy and copying a block of code from somewhere else without realizing that I replaced a hard-coded file name with a variable.  You wouldn't believe how long this had me stumped.  I just couldn't figure out the *permission* problem, when it had nothing to do with permissions.  Hopefully this will help someone else come to this realization quicker than for me.

Answer (score 1):

Two more things to try:

```
lsattr /var/log/apache2/load.log
```

This will check the extended atributes of your log fie. One of the attributes is immutable that makes your file readonly regardles of user rights.

and

```
ls -Z /var/log/apache2/load.log
```

This will show you the SELinux context and is only relevant for RedHat / Hardened Gentoo based distributions (in which case you should also receive much more errors and warnings in your system logs)